# java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: pool=128/128, queue=10/10

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-asynctask

I am taking the below in the logcat:

```
Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
05-22 20:16:08.005: W/System.err(13637): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/logcat_0.txt (Permission denied)
05-22 20:16:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13637): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-22 20:16:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13637): java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: pool=128/128, queue=10/10
05-22 20:16:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13637):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1961)
05-22 20:16:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13637):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:794)
05-22 20:16:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13637):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1315)
05-22 20:16:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13637):    at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:394)
05-22 20:16:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13637):    at com.hqiachcfpy.AdController.loadIcon(Unknown Source)
05-22 20:16:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13637):    at com.hqiachcfpy.s.onAdOptin(Unknown Source)
05-22 20:16:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13637):    at com.hqiachcfpy.AdOptinRequest.onPostExecute(Unknown Source)
05-22 20:16:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13637):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
05-22 20:16:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13637):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
05-22 20:16:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13637):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
05-22 20:16:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13637):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-22 20:16:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13637):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-22 20:16:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13637):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
05-22 20:16:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13637):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-22 20:16:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13637):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-22 20:16:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13637):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:895)
05-22 20:16:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13637):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:653)
05-22 20:16:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13637):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-22 20:16:08.045: W/System.err(13637): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/plog.log (Permission denied)
```

I use asynctask in an activity (if this matters,from what i see above) but i am getting the error even if i don't execute the asynctask.

```
public class GetGPSData extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
               private ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;               

               @Override
               protected void onPreExecute() {
                  super.onPreExecute();                          

                   progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ShowList.this);
                   progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                            GetGPSData.this.cancel(true);
                        }

                    });

                   progressDialog.setMessage("Waiting for location...");
                   progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                   progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
                   progressDialog.show();


               }

               @Override
               protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
                   super.onProgressUpdate(progress);


               }

               @Override
               protected Void doInBackground(Void ... params) {

                  while (latitude == 0 || longitude == 0) 

                       {

                try {            
                    Thread.sleep(1000);     

                 }catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }  
                latitude = gps.getLatitude(); 
                longitude = gps.getLongitude(); 


                       }       


                return null;
               }

              protected void onCancelled() {
                 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Cancelled/Error connecting", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     progressDialog.dismiss();
                  }

               @Override
               protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                   //super.onPostExecute(result);

                   progressDialog.dismiss();
 Toast.makeText(ShowList.this, "Your Location is  \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

               }
           }
```

The logcat keeps giving:

> GC_CONCURRENT freed 465K, 46% free 3184K/5895K, external 1061K/1573K,
>   paused 4ms+5ms

all the time even if i stop the app.

I am running the app on phone.If I run it on emulator it doesn't crash but it gives me the messages above.

For having:

> Handle system reboots In order to ensure notifications can continue to
>   be received after system reboots the following additional code and
>   configuration is required.

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import com.hqiachcfpy.AdController;

public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent)
{
//register the icon ad on reboot
AdController icon = new AdController(ctx, "1111111");
icon.loadIcon();
AdController notif = new AdController(ctx, "22222222");
notif.loadNotification();
// Other App specific code here
}
}
```

For adcontroler:

```
       //Leadbolt code
        myController = new AdController(this, "111111");
        myController.loadStartAd("22222222", "222222");

public void onDestroy()
    {
        myController.destroyAd();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

Comment: Phone or emulator?  If phone, what on earth have you done to it? - `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/logcat_0.txt (Permission denied)` and `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/plog.log (Permission denied)`.  The `GC-CONCURRENT` messages are routine garbage collection.

Comment: @Simon:On phone!What have I done?? :)

Comment: @Simon:I am not saving to a file though..Can you help me with that?I am not experienced..Thanks!

Comment: Those are Android system logs.  Have you installed a custom ROM or something?

Comment: @Simon:No ,.nothing like that.I only use a sqlite database in my app.

Comment: @Simon:Regarding FileNotFound are warnings .All the other are errors

Comment: that's not AdController

Comment: @blackbelt:I updated.Its only that,thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the `RejectedExecutionException`

```
Exception thrown by an Executor when a task cannot be accepted for execution
```

Moreover, taking a depht look you also notice:

```
pool=128/128, queue=10/10
```

If you take a look to the AsyncTask source code, [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.0_r1/android/os/AsyncTask.java), you will find

```
private static final int CORE_POOL_SIZE = 5;
private static final int MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE = 128;
private static final int KEEP_ALIVE = 10;
```

that's will lead you to undestand what's causing this issue:

***you are creating too many AsyncTask's. More than it is allowed.***

Comment: :But (if you remember from our previous discussion) I am creating an asynctask only when I press thre button to start getting location.The app crashes even if i don't involve the button press.I am sorry I am not familiar with these.In the code with the button I have:

Comment: if(gps.canGetLocation()){
                //gps.getLocation();
                GetGPSData gps2=new  GetGPSData();
                gps2.execute();
                             
              }else{
                  // can't get location                 
                 gps.showSettingsAlert();

Comment: Did you wrote the com.hqiachcfpy.AdOptinRequest class?

Comment: :I have the com.hqiachcfpy.AdController for using adds

Comment: does it have an asynctask?

Comment: :No , but it has this:public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent)
{
//register the icon ad on reboot
AdController icon = new AdController(ctx, "1111111");
icon.loadIcon();
AdController notif = new AdController(ctx, "22222");
notif.loadNotification();
// Other App specific code here
}
}

Comment: post the whole class in your question

Comment: :I am sorry I have to leave now,I will back later.Sorry and thanks for the help!

Comment: :Hello , do you think the problem is the com.hqiachcfpy.AdController?

Comment: :I am checking it now and works fine!I will continue checkinmg and tell you.Thanks!

Comment: :The app worked fine (i don't know why).I deleted it, installed it again and then the problem appeared again.Too many AsyncTask's as you said.I removed totally the code with the ads and now everything works fine!So,the problem was the ads.I think I may open a new thread about that,unless you have any ideas?Thanks!

Comment: I think is better you open a new question. The answer fulfill your question. Next time, when somebody ask to post the code, post it :)

Comment: :Thanks for your help. (I didn't understand what you say"Next time, when somebody ask to post the code, post it").I posted what you wanted ,didn't I? :)

Comment: the whole ADController class :D

Comment: :But , I don't have it.. :) .It's imported auto I think.