# AsyncTask using executeOnExcecutor uses too much memory and cause UI To Freeze

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I was instructed to use `AsyncTask` because multi-threads still caused my application to freeze. I do not believe I am using `AsyncTask` correctly. In the examples, I saw online, they did not have to call the method `Complete()`.

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/os/asynctask/android-asynctask-example/

I call `Complete()` in the case READ_MESSAGE and as expected it crashes my application. I am not sure what steps I need to take to fix this code. AsyncTask using executeOnExcecutor uses too much memory and cause UI To Freeze. I believe I am calling 'Complete()' incorrectly.

BluetoothChat full code

```
/**
 * This is the main Activity that displays the current chat session.
 */
@SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
public class BluetoothChat extends Activity {
    // Debugging
    private static final String TAG = "BluetoothChat";
    private static final boolean D = true;

    // Message types sent from the BluetoothChatService Handler
    public static final int MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE = 1;
    public static final int MESSAGE_READ = 2;
    public static final int MESSAGE_WRITE = 3;
    public static final int MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME = 4;
    public static final int MESSAGE_TOAST = 5;
    public static final int THREAD_POOL_SIZE = Integer.MAX;

    // Key names received from the BluetoothChatService Handler
    public static final String DEVICE_NAME = "device_name";
    public static final String TOAST = "toast";

    // Intent request codes
    private static final int REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_SECURE = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_INSECURE = 2;
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 3;

    // Layout Views
    private ListView mConversationView;
    private EditText mOutEditText;
    private Button mSendButton;
    public Button mFunctionButton;
    public Button seizureResult;
    public double [][]stored = new double[8000][1];
    public static HjorthClass finalValue;
    public int a;
    public Handler handler;
    public static boolean potato = false;
    public String transfer;
    public boolean bool;

    // Name of the connected device
    private String mConnectedDeviceName = null;
    // Array adapter for the conversation thread
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mConversationArrayAdapter;
    // String buffer for outgoing messages
    private StringBuffer mOutStringBuffer;
    // Local Bluetooth adapter
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = null;
    // Member object for the chat services
    private BluetoothChatService mChatService = null;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        if(D) Log.e(TAG, "+++ ON CREATE +++");

        // Set up the window layout
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        setTitle("Seizure Detection Helmet Application");

        handler = new Handler();
        mFunctionButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.functions);
        seizureResult  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.SeizureResult);

        mFunctionButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent z = new Intent(BluetoothChat.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(z);
            }

        });
        seizureResult.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Value =="+bool, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        });

        // Get local Bluetooth adapter
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        // If the adapter is null, then Bluetooth is not supported
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if(D) Log.e(TAG, "++ ON START ++");

        // If BT is not on, request that it be enabled.
        // setupChat() will then be called during onActivityResult
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        // Otherwise, setup the chat session
        } else {
            if (mChatService == null) setupChat();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(D) Log.e(TAG, "+ ON RESUME +");

        // Performing this check in onResume() covers the case in which BT was
        // not enabled during onStart(), so we were paused to enable it...
        // onResume() will be called when ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE activity returns.
        if (mChatService != null) {
            // Only if the state is STATE_NONE, do we know that we haven't started already
            if (mChatService.getState() == BluetoothChatService.STATE_NONE) {
              // Start the Bluetooth chat services
              mChatService.start();
            }
        }
    }

    private void setupChat() {
        Log.d(TAG, "setupChat()");

        // Initialize the array adapter for the conversation thread
        mConversationArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.message);
        mConversationView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.in);
        mConversationView.setAdapter(mConversationArrayAdapter);

        // Initialize the compose field with a listener for the return key
        mOutEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_out);
        mOutEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(mWriteListener);

        // Initialize the send button with a listener that for click events
        mSendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send);
        mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Send a message using content of the edit text widget
                TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_out);
                String message = view.getText().toString();
                sendMessage(message);
            }
        });

        // Initialize the BluetoothChatService to perform bluetooth connections
        mChatService = new BluetoothChatService(this, mHandler);

        // Initialize the buffer for outgoing messages
        mOutStringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(D) Log.e(TAG, "- ON PAUSE -");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if(D) Log.e(TAG, "-- ON STOP --");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // Stop the Bluetooth chat services
        if (mChatService != null) mChatService.stop();
        if(D) Log.e(TAG, "--- ON DESTROY ---");
    }

    private void ensureDiscoverable() {
        if(D) Log.d(TAG, "ensure discoverable");
        if (mBluetoothAdapter.getScanMode() !=
            BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE) {
            Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
            discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
            startActivity(discoverableIntent);
        }
    }

    private class ProcessData extends AsyncTask<Boolean, Void, Boolean>
    {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Boolean... params) 
        {
        for(int a = 0; a<8000; a++)
        {
            try
            {
            if(transfer == null)
            {
                transfer = "0";
            }
            double[] convert = new double[1];
            for(int z=0; z <1;z++)
            {
            convert[z]= Double.parseDouble(transfer);
            }
            for(int j=0; j<1;j++)
            {
            stored[a][j]= convert[j];
            }
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException e)
            {
            }
            }
            finalValue = new HjorthClass(stored);
            bool = finalValue.returnSum();
            return bool;
        }
    }

    private final ExecutorService mThreadPoolExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREAD_POOL_SIZE);

    public void Complete()
    {
        ProcessData task = new ProcessData();
        task.executeOnExecutor(mThreadPoolExecutor,bool);
    }


    /**
     * Sends a message.
     * @param message  A string of text to send.
     */
    private void sendMessage(String message) {
        // Check that we're actually connected before trying anything
        if (mChatService.getState() != BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.not_connected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        // Check that there's actually something to send
        if (message.length() > 0) {
            // Get the message bytes and tell the BluetoothChatService to write
            byte[] send = message.getBytes();
            mChatService.write(send);

            // Reset out string buffer to zero and clear the edit text field
            mOutStringBuffer.setLength(0);
            mOutEditText.setText(mOutStringBuffer);
        }
    }

    // The action listener for the EditText widget, to listen for the return key
    private TextView.OnEditorActionListener mWriteListener =
        new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView view, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            // If the action is a key-up event on the return key, send the message
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_NULL && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                String message = view.getText().toString();
                sendMessage(message);
            }
            if(D) Log.i(TAG, "END onEditorAction");
            return true;
        }
    };




   /** private final void setStatus(int resId) {
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setSubtitle(resId);
    }

    private final void setStatus(CharSequence subTitle) {
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setSubtitle(subTitle);
    } **/

    // The Handler that gets information back from the BluetoothChatService
    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(final Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
                if(D) Log.i(TAG, "MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE: " + msg.arg1);
                switch (msg.arg1) {
                case BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTED:
                    //setStatus(getString(R.string.title_connected_to, mConnectedDeviceName));
                    mConversationArrayAdapter.clear();
                    break;
                case BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTING:
                   // setStatus(R.string.title_connecting);
                    break;
                case BluetoothChatService.STATE_LISTEN:
                case BluetoothChatService.STATE_NONE:
                    //setStatus(R.string.title_not_connected);
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case MESSAGE_WRITE:
                byte[] writeBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                // construct a string from the buffer
                String writeMessage = new String(writeBuf);
                mConversationArrayAdapter.add("Me:  " + writeMessage);
                break;
            case MESSAGE_READ:
            byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                String readMessage = new String(readBuf,0,msg.arg1);
                transfer = readMessage;
                mConversationArrayAdapter.add("Voltage: "+ transfer);
                Complete();
                break;


            case MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME:
                // save the connected device's name
                mConnectedDeviceName = msg.getData().getString(DEVICE_NAME);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected to "
                               + mConnectedDeviceName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case MESSAGE_TOAST:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg.getData().getString(TOAST),
                               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(D) Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult " + resultCode);
        switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_SECURE:
            // When DeviceListActivity returns with a device to connect
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                connectDevice(data, true);
            }
            break;
        case REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_INSECURE:
            // When DeviceListActivity returns with a device to connect
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                connectDevice(data, false);
            }
            break;
        case REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:
            // When the request to enable Bluetooth returns
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // Bluetooth is now enabled, so set up a chat session
                setupChat();
            } else {
                // User did not enable Bluetooth or an error occurred
                Log.d(TAG, "BT not enabled");
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.bt_not_enabled_leaving, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    private void connectDevice(Intent data, boolean secure) {
        // Get the device MAC address
        String address = data.getExtras()
            .getString(DeviceListActivity.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS);
        // Get the BluetoothDevice object
        BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
        // Attempt to connect to the device
        mChatService.connect(device, secure);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.option_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Intent serverIntent = null;
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.secure_connect_scan:
            // Launch the DeviceListActivity to see devices and do scan
            serverIntent = new Intent(this, DeviceListActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(serverIntent, REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_SECURE);
            return true;
        case R.id.insecure_connect_scan:
            // Launch the DeviceListActivity to see devices and do scan
            serverIntent = new Intent(this, DeviceListActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(serverIntent, REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_INSECURE);
            return true;
        case R.id.discoverable:
            // Ensure this device is discoverable by others
            ensureDiscoverable();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


}
```

Comment: Why not use onPostExecute() that actually triggers after doInBackground() and returns the result you need from thread

Comment: protected void onPostExecute(Boolean bool) {
   // execution of result of Long time consuming operation
   finalResult.setText("Value of Boolean" + bool);
  } Something like that?

Comment: `RejectedExecutionException: pool=128/128, queue=10/10`. Does it suggest you  nothing ? Is HjorthClass that send the message?

Comment: My best guess is that its something along the lines of GC_ALLOCATE and GC_CONCURRENT? Could you please explain?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. HjorthClass takes the Variance of the Array that is stored, checks if it is above a value, and then returns true or false with the returnSum() method.

Comment: You are creating too many AsyncTasks and the system fails to allocate so many threads. The same question was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16698015/java-util-concurrent-rejectedexecutionexception-pool-128-128-queue-10-10

Comment: @user3495522 use task.`executeOnExecutor` instead to resolve the problem. Please see my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like my initial answer was too short and got converted to a comment :(. As it's actually an answer and not a comment I pasted it once more.

You are creating too many AsyncTasks and the system fails to allocate so many threads. The same question was answered here: [java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: pool=128/128, queue=10/10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16698015/java-util-concurrent-rejectedexecutionexception-pool-128-128-queue-10-10)

Comment: Thank you. Now the question is what do I do to fix that issue?

Comment: You are creating too many tasks too often. That means before the previous ones have the time to finish you are starting others doing the same thing. I don't know your use case but I assume you can ignore some of those events sent to the handler as the processing would anyway be overlapping. Maybe ignore the messages unless more than a few seconds passed since the previous received one?

Answer (score 0):

`RejectedExecutionException` you have is caused by the *limited capacity of the queue*, which keeps waiting tasks (and not by the size of a thread pool).

Default capacity of the queue is 10.

If you want to have more tasks queued run them with [executeOnExecutor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor%28java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20Params...%29) instead of `execute` (on android > 3.0):

```
// create fixed-size thread pool for Executor 
private final ExecutorService mThreadPoolExecutor = 
    Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREAD_POOL_SIZE);

// then execute your task
task.executeOnExecutor(mThreadPoolExecutor, bool);
```

In this case queue capacity will be equal to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` instead of 10 and you won't have tasks rejected (watch out however for not running out of memory submitting too many tasks).

I also recommend renaming your `Boolean bool` variable, looks very confusing.

Comment: My application crashed immediately, I got the error java.lang.NoSuchMethod.I'm assuming my android is not greater than 3.0

Comment: Are there any solutions for Android phone <3.0?

Comment: Could you please check your device API ? (Settings -> about device), and also what is `minSdkVersion` for the app (in AndroidManifest.xml) ?

Comment: Android Version 2.3.6. minSDK version is 10

Comment: I tried it on Samsung Galaxy S2 with version 4.0.4. However, that runs out of Memory like you suggested

Comment: as for support of < 11 versions, it is not straightforward, but doable. You might need to use Executors(threadPool) + tasks and calling back to UI thread with handlers, but that is not the major issue here, since you also crash on 4.0.4 you are obviously submitting too many tasks (perhaps endless loop somewhere ?). Could you post your code which sends messages to your handler ? Also, is this handler the only place you call `Complete`/submit new task ?

Comment: Yes, this is the only place I call Complete();. Let's stick with the 4.0.4 version, since that will be easier to manipulate I'm assuming. I will post the code for the whole Bluetoothchat.