# Android error unexpected

Tags: android

i m getting an unexpected error don't know where i am wrong about this code please help me to figure out and where necessary change have to take place let me know

this is my post to server code please have a look and tell me where is the problem

```
class MakemeOnline extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        String xuserid = "",success="",userNaam;
        int result = 0;
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
            String number = user.get(SManager.KEY_EMAIL);
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name",number));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("live",live));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",username));
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(Login_url, "POST", params);
            Log.d("Connecting", json.toString());
            try {
                success = json.getString(TAG_SUCCESS);
                result = json.getInt("result");
                userNaam = json.getString("username");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            if(result == 1){
                if(!userNaam.trim().equals("ago") || userNaam.trim().equals(" ")){
                MessageActivity.update_seen(userNaam);
                }
            if(!success.equals("2.1")){
                scheduleTaskExecutor.shutdownNow(); 
                finish();
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Download.class);
                 startActivity(i);
            }
        }else{
            MessageActivity.update_seen("");
        }
        }}
```

---

```
11-07 18:17:41.218: E/AndroidRuntime(18412): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-07 18:17:41.218: E/AndroidRuntime(18412): Process: com.androidhive.pushnotifications, PID: 18412
11-07 18:17:41.218: E/AndroidRuntime(18412): java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task android.widget.TextView$3@426c0468 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@41935208[Running, pool size = 5, active threads = 5, queued tasks = 128, completed tasks = 164]
11-07 18:17:41.218: E/AndroidRuntime(18412):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2011)
11-07 18:17:41.218: E/AndroidRuntime(18412):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:793)
11-07 18:17:41.218: E/AndroidRuntime(18412):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1339)
11-07 18:17:41.218: E/AndroidRuntime(18412):    at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:604)
11-07 18:17:41.218: E/AndroidRuntime(18412):    at android.widget.TextView.updateTextServicesLocaleAsync(TextView.java:8078)
11-07 18:17:41.218: E/AndroidRuntime(18412):    at android.widget.TextView.getTextServicesLocale(TextView.java:8034)
11-07 18:17:41.218: E/AndroidRuntime(18412):    at android.widget.TextView.getSpellCheckerLocale(TextView.java:8071)
11-07 18:17:41.218: E/AndroidRuntime(18412):    at android.widget.SpellChecker.spellCheck(SpellChecker.java:228)
11-07 18:17:41.218: E/AndroidRuntime(18412):    at android.widget.Editor.updateSpellCheckSpans(Editor.java:510)
11-07 18:17:41.218: E/AndroidRuntime(18412):    at android.widget.Editor.sendOnTextChanged(Editor.java:986)
11-07 18:17:41.218: E/AndroidRuntime(18412):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7423)
11-07 18:17:41.218: E/AndroidRuntime(18412):    at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:7478)
11-07 18:17:41.218: E/AndroidRuntime(18412):    at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:9198)
11-07 18:17:41.218: E/AndroidRuntime(18412):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:962)
11-07 18:17:41.218: E/AndroidRuntime(18412):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:496)
11-07 18:17:41.218: E/AndroidRuntime(18412):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:435)
11-07 18:17:41.218: E/AndroidRuntime(18412):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:30)
11-07 18:17:41.218: E/AndroidRuntime(18412):    at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.replaceText(BaseInputConnection.java:683)
11-07 18:17:41.218: E/AndroidRuntime(18412):    at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.setComposingText(BaseInputConnection.java:438)
11-07 18:17:41.218: E/AndroidRuntime(18412):    at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:333)
11-07 18:17:41.218: E/AndroidRuntime(18412):    at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:77)
11-07 18:17:41.218: E/AndroidRuntime(18412):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-07 18:17:41.218: E/AndroidRuntime(18412):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-07 18:17:41.218: E/AndroidRuntime(18412):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
11-07 18:17:41.218: E/AndroidRuntime(18412):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-07 18:17:41.218: E/AndroidRuntime(18412):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-07 18:17:41.218: E/AndroidRuntime(18412):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
11-07 18:17:41.218: E/AndroidRuntime(18412):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
11-07 18:17:41.218: E/AndroidRuntime(18412):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Sophia, please post your code, without seeing your code how can people solve it?

Comment: Show your code. Error says you are using AsyncTask or Thread.

Comment: without code how realize why this error came.

Comment: i have a lot of activity but where do i get error i don't know so what code do you require

Comment: Are you using AsyncTask ?

Comment: Is it ThreadPoolExecutor error

Comment: yes i am using AsyncTask

Comment: -1 for Not provide enough detail.

Comment: You are working on GCM right ? and in what exectly you get error ?

Comment: @SophiaKhan Ok then just show that class.

Comment: @NikPatel which detail you want

Comment: Its Required more information with code

Comment: @SophiaKhan in which class you are using pushnotification service code?

Comment: @GulnazGhanchi i can't figure out what error i m getting but yes i am using Gcm

Comment: @pratt do u want code for sending push notification or receiving push notification

Comment: @SophiaKhan paste GCM related class here.

Comment: @SophiaKhan Yes, post that both class.

Comment: Gcm recievr or broadcast reciever

Comment: @SophiaKhan both one

Comment: for sending gcm i m using php server i m posting receiver of gcm

Comment: wait a minute i m opening my code

Comment: @SophiaKhan Got the thing, you are creating too many AsyncTask's. More than it is allowed. See this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16698015/java-util-concurrent-rejectedexecutionexception-pool-128-128-queue-10-10

Comment: @pratt thanks for the help but Right now i have figure out my error it was my json parser error thanks for the support

Comment: @SophiaKhan hmmm its okay, happy coding!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is occuring because,you are creating too many AsyncTask's. More than it is allowed.AsyncTask class itself have some limit to create it. So you are created more then it is allowed. See this [link](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/cupcake/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java)

```
private static final int CORE_POOL_SIZE = 5;
private static final int MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE = 128;
private static final int KEEP_ALIVE = 10;
```

Above are all values to create AsyncTask at its maximum.